# reads variable from a text file and set it to current PowerShell session env variable

Tags: powershell, variables, environment-variables, environment

let's say that I have a text file that defines some variables something like this

```
file : .env

USER=user
DB_NAME=userDB
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

and I want PowerShell to read the text file and export it to current session so when I have a program that run from the session same and reads the variable from env it will recognize the variable above, how do i do that in PowerShell ?

Comment: take a look at the built in  stuff >>> `Get-Help ConvertFrom-StringData` [*grin*]

Comment: Your question is lacking details, it's also lacking on what have you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement combined with the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) and use of [`Set-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-item) with the `Env:` drive to set environment variables for the current process:

```
switch -File .env {
  default {
    $name, $value = $_.Trim() -split '=', 2
    if ($name -and $name[0] -ne '#') { # ignore blank and comment lines.
      Set-Item "Env:$name" $value
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Alternatively, you could use `Get-Content .env | ForEach-Object { ... }` - but, for technical reasons, that is significantly slower, as of PowerShell 7.2.3 (though, in a given use case, that may not matter in practice):

- `Get-Content` decorates each line read from its input file with [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) properties, which slows things down, even though these properties *typically* aren't needed.

  - [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537) asks for an *opt-out* to improve performance.
- The [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlets are *inefficiently implemented*.

  - [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982) asks that this be fixed.