# Powershell create multiple environment variables from .env file

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, powershell-3.0

I created a .env file to host some api authentication keys for my various python and powershell scripts. I'm trying to get my powershell script to read the file and set the variables, but it doesn't seem to work. This is the command I'm using to set the variables, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70736582/45375).

```
switch -File .\wkspaces\IT-Scripts\New-UserCredentials.env {
    default {
      $name, $value = $_.Trim() -split '=', 2
      if ($name -and $name[0] -ne '#') { # ignore blank and comment lines.
        Set-Item "Env:$name" $value
      }
    }
  }
```

When I try to call the variable, it's just blank as if it doesn't exist. I am not using any spaces between the name and value in the .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question, which *defines* environment variables based on `.env` files, is sound.

However, *accessing* (the resulting) environment variables, using [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) via `$env:`, *situationally* requires enclosing the environment-variable names in `{...}`, namely if the names happen to contain characters that aren't by default recognized as part of an *identifier* by PowerShell.

For instance, the following defines an environment variable named `foo-bar`, with value `baz`, using PowerShell's [environment provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider):

```bash
Set-Item 'Env:foo-bar' 'baz'
```

Because `foo-bar` by default isn't recognized as an identifier by PowerShell, due to the embedded `-` character - be it as the name of a regular (shell-only) variable (`$` prefix) or that of an environment variable via namespace variable notation (`$env:` prefix) - enclosure of the name, including the namespace prefix, if any, in `{...}` is required:

```bash
# Note: Without {...} enclosure, this would fail.
${env:foo-bar}  # -> 'baz'
```